# How do I monitor folder and move the file out of it?

Tags: shell

I need a shell to monitor for new files in a folder and I will receive two files: x.DONE and x.txt, and as soon as I receive the x.DONE I need to get the related x.txt and move out of this folder and delete the .DONE.

Can someone please help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try to run this line in the directory you expect to find x.DONE in:

```
while [ ! -f *.DONE.pgp ]; do sleep 1 ; done ; for f in *.DONE.pgp ; do mv ${f%%.*}.XML.pgp destination-directory ; rm  ${f%%.*}.DONE.pgp ; done
```

To make this code more clear to understand this is not one-liner :

```
while [ ! -f *.DONE.pgp ]; do sleep 1 ; done
for f in *.DONE.pgp ; do
    mv ${f%%.*}.XML.pgp destination-directory
    rm  ${f%%.*}.DONE.pgp
done
```

This code assumes that the *.DONE.pgp  file appears when *.XML.pgp file does.
In case it does not you can do something like that:

```
    if [ -f ${f%%.*}.XML.pgp ]; then
        mv ${f%%.*}.XML.pgp destination-directory
    else
        echo ${f%%.*}.DONE.pgp without ${f%%.*}.XML.pgp detected.
    fi
```

Comment: But I will not know the name of the file, it can be y.DONE, z.DONE.. and I need to move the corresponding .txt file out of the folder...

Comment: @LeandroToshioTakeda: Ah, so you want *.DONE, not just x.DONE. Please see new code. Small fix to move .txt file.

Comment: There is just a quick modification needed here, the file will be:

filename.DONE.pgp
filename.XML.pgp

I need the .DONE.pgp removed, and the .XML.pgp moved... again, when I receive both, with same name. Corresponding ones.

Comment: Tagging you now... :)

Comment: Results:

filename.XML.DONE.DONE.pgp without filename.XML.DONE.XML.pgp detected.

Comment: @LeandroToshioTakeda - let me check it.

Comment: @LeandroToshioTakeda Done. Had to change single % to %%. When f=a.DONE.pgp ${f%.*} is a.DONE, while we want ${f%%.*} which returns a

Comment: What about this?

for f in * ; do
    if [ -f ${f%.*}.DONE.pgp ]; then
        echo "Move: ${f%.*}.pgp"
        echo "Delete: ${f%.*}.DONE.pgp"
    else
        echo ${f%.*} without ${f%.*} detected.
    fi
done

Comment: You need to use %%, not % because we want to take front part of the file name. Also you cannot use `for f in *` as it will list all the files, and you simply don't want to do 'too much' if it is not needed. Anyway, please check my fix in the main answer. I have run it on my machine, and it works.

Comment: Last question... how can I change it to run out of the folder I want?

Comment: Do you want to put this part of the code into a script, and run it from a different location? It will complicate the matter more than needed. Let's assume X is this script. You can write the following: `( cd where-DONE-is ; X )`. This will ensure that it changes directory for this X script but the rest of the script is still in the current directory.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this (avoid polling every N seconds) :

```
#!/bin/bash

inotifywait -m . | while read dir event file; do
    [[ $event == CLOSE_WRITE* && "$file" =~ (x|DONE).txt ]] && case "$file" in
        x.txt) file_content="$(<x.txt)" ;;
        DONE.txt) mv x.txt /tmp; rm DONE.txt ;;
    esac
```

From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify :

> One major use is in desktop search utilities like Beagle, where its functionality permits reindexing of changed files without scanning the filesystem for changes every few minutes, which would be very inefficient.

---

for red-hat like distro, take a look to the `inotify-tools` package.

Comment: Looks nice, although I have 2.6.18-53.1.19.el5, and it does not have inotifywait :( Which rpm is it in?

Comment: I don't have inotifywait